# When using GLS, how do I compute the conditional variance of the error term?

Tags: regression, factor-analysis

I want to use generalized least squares (GLS) to estimate $\beta$ in

$$r = X\beta + u$$

where $r$ is a vector of stock returns and $X$ is a matrix of factor exposures.  I choose GLS because the relationship

$$\hat{\beta} = (X^T\Omega^{-1}X)^{-1}X^T\Omega^{-1}r,$$

where $\Omega = Var(u | X)$ is the conditional variance of the error term, will allow me to express the factors in terms of the original vector $r$:

$$\beta_k = \sum_{n = 1}^{k} c_{k,n}  r_n.$$

My question is:  **When using GLS, how can I compute $\Omega$?**

**EDIT:** This was previously a question on how to do it in R.  I've changed it to a more theoretical question:  I'll figure out the R way *after* I understand how to get $\Omega$.

Comment: I may be wrong, but GLS is a theoretical object which cannot be computed as such, since $\boldsymbol{\Omega}$ is unknown and unobservable. There are only 2nd order related objects such as WLS or FGLS, whose aim is approximating and working with $\hat{\boldsymbol{\Omega}}$, supposed to be correct asymptotically. But this is only true for heteroscedasticity. However, it may be possible to get a good approximation for autocorrelation as well using Bayesian estimation technics. So it is going to be interesting to know how R's GLS really is. Probably only a feasible one.

Comment: I'm trying to emulate the thought experiment from "Active Portfolio Management, 2nd edition" by Grinold & Kahn (2000) on pp. 73-74.  They refer to $\Omega^{-1}$ as the "diagonal matrix of GLS regression weights", but this terminology doesn't quite fit in with everything I'm learning about GLS at the moment.

Comment: $\Omega^{-1}$ diagonal (and so is $\Omega$)  relates to deal only with heteroscedasticity. So using the flexible approach discussed in Wooldridge page 277 is probably the one you are implicitly searching for. That being said, I don't know if you can capture it using R's GLS.

Comment: @Tnerual thanks.  I've changed the question from "How to get $\Omega$ in R" to "How to get $\Omega$".  I clearly need more help with the theory than the practice.  I'm not familiar with Wooldridge.

Comment: Lookup [feasible GLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_least_squares#Feasible_generalized_least_squares). Beware the pitfalls of feasible GLS... generally a more conservative approach is to use ordinary least squares and a consistent estimator for the standard errors depending on if you have heteroscedasticity, clusters etc...

Comment: It is impossible to estimate diagonal $\Omega$ if you do not specify the structure of it. Currently, # of unknown parameters in $\Omega$ = # of observations. You need to find a way to decrease the # of parameters in $\Omega$

Comment: Are you ok with the following answer ?

Comment: @Tnerual Are you referring to the one answer given? It seems promising but I haven't had time to try it in practice. Since it answers the question thoroughly it will probably win the bounty though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my perspective, there are two possibilities for you.

**Solution from classical Econometrics**

Either you choose the path of standard econometrics (i.e. the Wooldridge solution) and you try to approximate the weights within $\Omega$ by first applying a linear regression $\hat{\beta}=(X'X)^{-1}X'y$ and using the residuals $\hat{u}=y-X\hat{\beta}$ in order to approximate the weights in via $\hat{\Omega}=\text{diag}\{\hat{u}_i^2\}_{i=1,...,N}$. This approach is called weighted least-squares and is helpful in presence of heteroscedasticity.

Another classical idea from econometrics is using the residuals from the first stage (the $\hat{u}$'s) for a regression framework that allows  the residuals to depend on the covariates. I.e. using something like $\hat{u}^2=\exp(Z\gamma)$, where $Z$ is a subset of $X$. After that you can use the fitted values from this regression (call them $\hat{\omega}$) in order to define your weights $\hat{\Omega}=\text{diag}\{\hat{\omega}_i\}_{i=1,...,N}$.

**Solution from Statistics**

If you want to stay within the framework of generalized linear models, I would recommend you the application of hierarchical generalized linear models (HGLM, see https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2010-2/RJournal_2010-2_Roennegaard~et~al.pdf for a nice implementation in R).

These are very flexible in modelling covariance structures and they do not rely on a two-step estimation procedure. The basic structure is given by

$$Y|\beta,\gamma,X \sim N (X\beta,\exp(Z\gamma)) .$$
With this approach it is possible to fit the dispersion term very flexible. And the nice thing of this approach is the possiblity to employ other distributions from the exponential family (i.e. you are not restricted to gaussian). On top of that, they also allow for a very convenient inclusion of random effects.